# Will the new iPad be world ready?

Tags: ipad, hardware, network, cellular-data

The specs for the third generation Verizon iPad say that it will be GSM/EDGE compatible. Does this mean that the Verizon new iPad will have a SIM card slot? Will I be better off with a Verizon iPad if I wanted the ability to connect to either CDMA or GSM networks?

**Edit:**

Will the Verizon model have a SIM tray? Will it be locked to Verizon? (Say I wanted to buy an iPad SIM card later from AT&T, would I have that option?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes.

#### (It's a "world iPad" for both the AT&T and Verizon model.)

Whether a device functions worldwide for a specific wireless standard depends on the frequency bands that it supports.

E.g. The new iPad supports LTE, but only the frequency bands 700 MHz and 2100 MHz which are not used outside the US.

The [iPhone 4S](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html) has been called a world phone, because it supports all the frequency band used for GSM [worldwide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_frequency_bands#GSM_frequency_usage_across_the_world):

- 850, 900, 1800, 1900 MHz

The [new iPad](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/) supports the same GSM frequency bands for **both** the AT&T and Verizon model. Therefore it's a "world iPad".

Of course you need a SIM-tray, to make use of this. Like the iPhone, the iPad has a Micro-SIM card tray.

Comment: Actually I think the answer is YES for GSM, but NO for LTE because (as you mentioned) the supported LTE bands are not used outside the US. So the initial "Yes." in your answer might be kind of misleading.

Comment: @patrix Yeah, this is sort of confusing. There actually is no such defined term as *world phone*. I believe the iPhone 4S is called a world *phone* as GSM is primarily used for making calls. LTE is not not used for making phone calls as it draws a lot more power. It would not make sense to call bind the term world phone to LTE support.

Comment: Do both models have the SIM tray?

Comment: @Moshe Apple does not distinguish between the models in the [tech specs](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/) when it comes to input/output connections. Therefore I think that both models have a SIM tray.

Comment: From http://www.apple.com/ipad/4g/: "iPad with Wi-Fi + 4G models for AT&T and for Verizon connect to GSM/UMTS networks worldwide." Both models must have a SIM tray for that assertion to work.